# remove hastag and keep word in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove hastag but still keep the words in that hastag. for example :

#ihateyousomuch

the output that i want is 'I hate you so much'

I try many code but doesnt work and the output is "ihateyousomuch"

Comment: Regex can remove the # but it can't detect meaningful words on its own, you will have to code that part.

Comment: i try to use this text = " ".join(word.strip() for word in re.split('#|_', text)) but it keep the output is "ihateyousomuch" not I hate you so much'

Comment: are you certain that these words in hashtag are not splitted with "_" or "-" ?

Comment: yes. the word in hastag arent splitted with  "_" or "-".  the word just "ihateyousomuch"

Comment: you need to use a dictionary to check if "ihateyousomuch" when splitted will form meaning full words so that you doesn't split it like 'ihat eyo uoso much'

Comment: `('#ihateyousomuch').strip('#')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is to use the [`wordninja`](https://github.com/keredson/wordninja) library. This library is not 100% accurate but helps in such cases.

```
#pip install wordninja

import wordninja

string = '#ihateyousomuch'

result = " ".join(wordninja.split(string.replace('#', '')))

print(result)
```

Prints

```
i hate you so much
```